# OData query $filter with multiple conditions

Tags: php, filter, odata, multiple-conditions

I got two tables

patient table

```
+----+-------------+-----+
| id | name        | age |
+----+-------------+-----+
|  1 | justin john |  49 |
|  2 | tim blake   |  51 |
+----+-------------+-----+

checkup table
+-----+------------+------------+
| cid | patient_id | date       |
+-----+------------+------------+
|   1 |          1 | 2016-11-02 |
|   2 |          2 | 2016-11-03 |
+-----+------------+------------+
```

i want to join both tables on the following condition

```
SELECT patient.id, patient.name, patient.age, checkup.date FROM patient LEFT JOIN checkup ON patient.id = checkup.patient_id WHERE patient.age > 50 AND checkup.date = '2016-11-03'
```

how can i achieve the above with OData $filter. Is $filter only applicable to top-level entity set patient ?

Answer (score 2):

You can filter on related objects using the `any` and `all` filters for example here is a URL for the example OData TripPin services that shows how this can be used: [http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinServiceRW/People?$filter=UserName eq 'russellwhyte' and Trips/any(x: x/Name eq 'Trip in US')](http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinServiceRW/People?$filter=UserName%20eq%20'russellwhyte'%20and%20Trips/any(x:%20x/Name%20eq%20'Trip%20in%20US'))

This URL filters on the `UserName` property of the `Person` and the `Name` property of the related `Trip`